# Default filter for Model in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Let's say I have the following table called `my_table`

| id | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | b |
| 4 | a |

I want to have two models that rely on the same table, but when I query each they will return only results with a default filter on `type` column.
So for example -

```
def filter_by_a():
    ...

def filter_by_b():
    ...

class ModelA(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'

    default_filter = filter_by_a

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = db.Column(db.String)

class ModelB(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'

    default_filter = filter_by_b

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = db.Column(db.String)
```

When I use `db.session.query(ModelA)` the results are

| id | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 4 | a |

And when I use `db.session.query(ModelB)` the results are

| id | type |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | b |

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Sounds a bit like you might be after single table inheritance, but not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/inheritance.html#single-table-inheritance

```
class MyTableModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = db.Column(db.String)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on': type
    }

class ModelA(MyTableModel):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'a'
    }

class ModelB(MyTableModel):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'b'
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution i would go with. It comes with also a benefit of creating data using `ModelA` or `ModelB` will set the `type` value correctly.

However, the behavior of querying using such a simple query as `session.query(ModelA)` will not work as expected in `sqlalchemy>=1.4` (but did work as you want in previous versions.

Please see this [Stricter behavior when querying inheritance mappings using custom queries](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_14.html#stricter-behavior-when-querying-inheritance-mappings-using-custom-queries) to learn more on the topic.